# Users can add elements to a flask form?

Tags: forms, flask, flask-wtforms

I am using flask wtforms etc. to develop an email templating app. Each paragraph of the email to be sent is entered into a different text box (that reason being that not all paragraphs will go to all to all email recipients).

I cannot know in advance how many paragraphs the user will wish to input. I can ask them before they reach the templating functionality and render a form based on their input, but I would much rather they be able to add elements to the form themselves. They should be able to add a field, and subtract a field (a bit like when you have to add an employment history when  you apply for a job).

I have been looking around but I dont see anything like this in the flask/wtforms docs. What should I be looking into?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Javascript on the client side to control the dynamic frontend. Simple show/hide `<divs>` should suffice.

At the backend the fastest method is to preallocate the form:

```
SubmitForm(FlaskForm)
    input1 = String(..)
    input2 = String(validators=[Optional()])
    .. 
    inputN = String(validators=[Optional()])
```

Then you will parse the form and as many forms as the user pasted in (to a maximum). Backend code can figure out how many forms were input.